# Unity 3d, BoxCollider for sword

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

So I'm working on a First-person sword game, I have the basic fighting setup but if you walk into an enemy they take damage from the collider, I want to have the Collider disabled until I use my attack button and then go back to disabled so you can't just walk into enemies. (C#, Unity 2020.2, 3d)

Here is the sword Animation Script which I would like to also have the Box Collider change in this as well for simple accessibility.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sword : MonoBehaviour
{
     Animator anim;

     private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
   private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        anim.SetBool("Attacking", true);
        else if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
        anim.SetBool("Attacking", false);
    }
    
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to your Collider the same way you got your Animator and after that, you can do `collider.enabled = false` to disable it.

You can also go there to read more about colliders: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html

Comment: I also see that you deal with the inputs in your update, I recommend that you go look at input actions, they are a really nice way to do your inputs. https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.9/manual/Actions.html

Comment: So i added  the collider.enabled = false

Comment: I added this to the Update function col is getting the component for the BoxCollider but the box collider stays no matter what, i only want it to appear when clicked.                   
 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        Col.enabled = true;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        Col.enabled = false;

Comment: You should put it in the same ifs of the animations because you don't need to check twice if the button is down or up

Answer (score 0):

So with the code there is an animator attached and a Collider attached to the script, when left clicked the animation will play and the collider will turn on

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sword : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    Collider Col;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Col = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        anim.SetBool("Attacking", true);
        else if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
        anim.SetBool("Attacking", false);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        Col.enabled = true;
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
        Col.enabled = false;
    }
```